# Cache CSS and JS files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

When I refresh my website in less than 2-3 minutes, Firebug shows these nice requests:

```
1. /core.css          304 Not modified
2. /core.js           304 Not modified
3. /background.jpg    304 Not modified
```

BUT when I refresh after >3 minutes, I get:

```
1. /core.css          200 OK
2. /core.js           200 OK
3. /background.jpg    304 Not modified
```

**Why my CSS and JS files are downloaded again and images aren't?**

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3, I DON'T use `[OutputCache]`, and in my `/Content` folder (where all css, js and img files live in subfolders) I have this Web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

which sets HTTP header `Cache-Control: max-age=86400` ONLY. So basically CSS, JS and images are treated the same way, but somehow CSS and JS don't get cached for a longer period... why is that?

Comment: Why don't you use `[OutputCache]`?

Comment: Because this is static content. Here I'm interested about static content caching, I doubt that it has anything to do with ASP.NET MVC, but I mentioned it because I don't know everything and maybe there's some solution...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hopefully this will help: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache

> The `<clientCache>` element of the [`<staticContent>`](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent) element specifies cache-related HTTP headers that IIS 7 and later sends to Web clients, which control how Web clients and proxy servers will cache the content that IIS 7 and later returns...

Comment: The effects of turning this on are tremendous if you're using jQuery with a couple of different plug-ins e.g jqGrid, at a minimum the stuff flying by in fiddler has been reduced.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs with IIS or with the Visual Studio web server? for some time perceived this behavior while developing (using the VS web server), but when publish it in IIS this not occur anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the bug in Firefox described [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=290032) ?

You could test this by opening the same page in another browser and check what get's loaded using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) or some other tool.

Comment: I just noticed that this bug was resolved at 2010-05-09. So this fix could be in the latest version of FF.

Comment: I do have the latest version :)