# How can I cache only js and css files in ASP.NET MVC website?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, caching, browser-cache

I have a requirement where I need only the js and css files to be cached. Other files or JSON data should not be cached.

How can I force the browser to download the js and css files only from the cache, not other data like JSON returned from AJAX calls, etc..

I am looking for client-side solutions where possible.

Comment: Use MVC [bundling](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: I'm using mvc bundling for caching. But I dont want json data in request headers of ajax call to be cached as it contains sensitive data. I want only the js and css files to be cached.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644748/cache-css-and-js-files check this

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041603/how-to-prevent-the-browser-from-caching-a-json-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105481/how-to-cache-css-images-and-js or this

Comment: My question here is different. I'm using client caching and my files are getting cached. But I don't want the ajax request header to be cached.

Comment: @user3263194 if JSON is only ever returned in POST requests, then you won't have a problem as this is not cached by the client. If it is returned in response to a GET request - assuming you are using JQUERY to make an AJAX request for it, there is a cache:false option - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I've updated the question to improve the capitalization and grammar, and removed extra text like "Please" and "Thank you". Stack Overflow is a technical site, not a forum, so we don't need pleasantries. You may wish to further differentiate your question from the existing questions pointed out in other comments.